# Is it possible to trace what exactly Magento is doing?

Tags: magento

Is it possible to see the route chosen, controller, etc.?

I know I can turn on the inline tracing but that doesn't really seem sufficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look into [Alan Storms Commerce Bug module](http://store.alanstorm.com/products/commerce-bug) and I would highly recommend setting up [X-Debug](http://xdebug.org/).

Comment: thanks for the feedback. kind of silly that this isn't built-in--especially since we have the enterprise version.

Comment: Know the feeling, work in Enterprise Edition all day as well.  Here's some debug tips I've posted up also: http://www.molotovbliss.com/debugging-tips-and-tricks-with-magento-commerce

Answer (score 1):

> Tracing what Magento is doing and how the code flow works

Best way is to use **PHP IDE** like **Eclipse** along with **Debugger** like **Xdebug**.

Here are some useful links on Debugging PHP applications with Xdebug:-

http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/articles/debugger/os-php-eclipse-pdt-debug-pdf.pdf

http://devzone.zend.com/article/2930